# How to play file form assets in jwplayer in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, media, jwplayer

i want some videohosting.
I have Ruby on rails server with jwplayer and custom assets:
i added folowing code to files:

application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "videos")
```

and

application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'swfobject' %>
<%= jwplayer_assets %>
```

in the page i put:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="Bvq5FKkZtlr35FLz/X5zAZi68CoLcmxpAubbYQ==";</script>
    <div id='myElement'>Loading the player ...</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var playerInstance = jwplayer('myElement');
  playerInstance.setup({ 
    file: 'a.mp4'
  });
</script>

 <div id="mediaplayer" align="center">
 </div>    

 <script type="text/javascript"> 

 jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
   flashplayer: "<%#= asset_path('player.swf') %>",
   image: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.jpg",
   file: "a.mpg",
   height: 270,
   width:480
 });
 </script>
```

ofcourse i have that files in the "assets/videos", but "Error loading media: File could not be played."
And in the console log:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Error playing media: MediaError http://10.10.0.3:3000/a.mp4
code: 4
```

Why jwplayer doesn't look in assets for these files?

Comment: If you go to http://10.10.0.3:3000/a.mp4 in the web browser, does it give you the file?

Comment: there is an error:

Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/a.mp4"

but i can't  udestand why?:(

Comment: I don't know either, but if you fix that, JW Player should start working.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: "a.mpg" is wrong path, we need to use "assets/a.mpg"